# Can not find credentials in AWS .NET SDK

Tags: .net, web-config, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a web app with the AWS .NET SDK. I am adding my credentials in using the credential file. In my web.config it looks like this.

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="profilename" />
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\AWS\credentials" />
<add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-1" />
```

My credentials file itself looks like this and it is located  at this path C:\AWS, it is saved under the title credentials.txt

```
[myname]
aws_access_key_id = my key
aws_secret_access_key = my s key
```

According to this document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/V2/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-config-creds.html this is set up correctly. I have set up the profile with an IAM Administrator role and the keys both match the keys given upon creation.

However when I try and create an EC2Client object I am greeted with this error

> Unable to find credentials
>
> Exception 1 of 4:
>
> System.ArgumentException: App.config does not contain credentials
> information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey or
> AWSProfileName.
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String
> profileName, String profilesLocation) in
> d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdk-v2\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
> 318
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentAWSCredentials..ctor() in
> d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdk-v2\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
> 590
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.b__1() in
> d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdk-v2\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
> 1117
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
> fallbackToAnonymous) in
> d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdk-v2\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
> 1137

I know I can hardcode the keys into the web.config or use the SDK store but I  need it to be done this way. Why can my code not find my credentials file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credentials.txt needs to be converted from a text file to a generic windows file (.file) for the application to recognise it.